# TypeScript AMD define with definition function

Tags: typescript, requirejs, amd

I'm wondering if there's a way in TypeScript to compile as AMD with a definition function as defined by RequireJS -  http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#deffunc

output would be:

```
//my/shirt.js now does setup work
//before returning its module definition.
define(function () {
    //Do setup work here

    return {
        color: "black",
        size: "unisize"
    }
});
```

All I seem to be able to do is compile to an AMD structure like:

```
define(["module"], function(module) {
    ...code etc
})
```